# Format number value from XX.X to .XXX java

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am receiving a value from a server that reads as a percentage, for example 77.5%.  How can get the value .775 just using:

```
String.format(Locale.getDefault(), formatPattern, floatValue);
```

I've consulted https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html, but it doesn't seem to cover my situation.

Note: I can only use the string format as we are placing the pattern into a config file.

Comment: What pattern are you using and what is the `floatValue` and what is the result you are getting?  Do you expect `.775` rather than `0.775`?

Comment: We are receiving 77.5 and would like it in the format .775. The pattern I have tried is %1$,.3f

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid the division by 100 and just moving the floating point to left two places by using :

```
double value = java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(77.5).movePointLeft(2).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String value = "75%";
Double aNumber = (Double.parseDouble(value.replace("%", "")))/100;
```

Comment: I can only use String.format(Locale.getDefault(), formatPattern, floatValue);

Comment: @KristyWelsh there is no format which will divide the value by 100. You can only format the value it is.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
String num = "75.5%";
String res = new DecimalFormat("#.000").format(Double.parseDouble(num.substring(0, num.length()-1))/100);
```